# Ruby resolv library how to exclude non-IPv4 addresses

Tags: ruby, resolv

I want to use [Resolv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html) library to resolve hostnames including 'localhost' but it lists non-IPv4 addresses also. I want to find out first IPv4 address. Looked at the library but could not find a way to do so. Does anyone know of a way to do this or should we go for other gems like Net:DNS or dnsruby?

Comment: Judging from the page you linked, can't you just do something like `ips.reject{ |ip| ip.is_a? Resolv::IPv6 }` on a list of addresses. On your linked page that would be after `ress.map { |r| r.address }` in their example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i right understand you can use `Resolv::IPv4::Regexp` and `Resolv::IPv6::Regexp` look example:

```
=> require 'resolv'
=> p Resolv.getaddress "www.ruby-lang.org"
#> "23.23.144.121"
=> ip = "23.23.144.121"
=> ip =~ Resolv::IPv4::Regex
#> 0
=> ip =~ Resolv::IPv6::Regex
#> nil
=> case ip
=> when Resolv::IPv4::Regex
=> puts "It's a valid IPv4 address."
=> when Resolv::IPv6::Regex
=> puts "It's a valid IPv6 address."
=> else
=> puts "It's not a valid IP address."
=> end
#> It's a valid IPv4 address.
```